# Filter records by date when record contains specific ID's

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to filter the RECORDS by last modified date (LastModifiedDate) column but I want this filter to work only when any record have status id's as 6 or 7. For other ID's it should return those records without checking for date filter.

Can anyone help me with the proper condition in `where`clause of below sql?

```
SELECT fd.[DocID], fd.[FolderName], fd.[AStatus], fd.[LastModifiedDate]
FROM FoldersDetail fd
INNER JOIN StatusMaster sm 
    ON sm.StatusID = fd.StatusID
INNER JOIN PriorityMaster pm 
    ON pm.PriorityID = fd.PriorityID
WHERE FD.StatusID IN (6,7) AND fd.LastModifiedDate > DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
```

This SQL filtering records but not returning other rows whose ID's are not 6 or 7.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: `AND` means both conditions must be true, you want `OR` which means either (or both) condition must be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT fd.[DocID], fd.[FolderName], fd.[AStatus], fd.[LastModifiedDate]
FROM FoldersDetail fd
INNER JOIN StatusMaster sm 
    ON sm.StatusID = fd.StatusID
INNER JOIN PriorityMaster pm 
    ON pm.PriorityID = fd.PriorityID
WHERE FD.StatusID NOT IN (6,7) OR fd.LastModifiedDate > DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
```

Basically if StatusID isn't 6 or 7, the `OR` is satisfied, if StatusID is 6 or 7, the right part of the `OR` is checked.